# is it possible to convert webp image without shell_exec() or exec() in rosell-dk packages?

Tags: php, shell-exec, webp

is it possible to convert .webp image without shell_exec() or exec() in rosell-dk packages ?
i am use rosell-dk package and install through composer. and rosell-dk package use shell_Exec() or exec() function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the [rosell-dk/webp-convert](https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-convert) package, it looks like the ['gd' converter](https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-convert/blob/master/src/Converters/Gd.php) uses the php-gd extension to convert from jpeg to webp without using any shell commands.

Based on the documentation you'd force the package to use the 'gd' converter like this:

```
 <?php
// Initialise your autoloader (this example is using Composer)
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use WebPConvert\WebPConvert;
$source = __DIR__ . '/logo.jpg';
$destination = __DIR__ . '/logo.jpg.webp';
$success = WebPConvert::convert($source, $destination, [
    'converters' => ['gd']
]);
```

Comment: using  'converters' => ['gd'] not working when i user     'converters' => ['cwebp'] then it works

Comment: The cwebp converter uses an external program to do the conversion and would use `shell_exec`. The gd converter doesn't, but requires that the php-gd extension be installed. Do you have the php-gd extension installed and enabled?

Comment: yes gd is install . and its working fine but some large image are not converted.

Comment: You might be running into a memory limit if it's only large files. Do you get any errors?

Comment: how can i set  max upload time

Comment: Check out [max_execution_time](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) in php.ini.